# Why subviews in UIViewController going with offset using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uistoryboard

Cant understand why in new Xcode there is 16.0f offset from left and right, when i add 0 leading/trailing constraints from subview to controller.view

[image: screen]

[image: constraint]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set them relative to the superview's margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting on the AutoLayout constraint `Relative to Margin`.

If you edit the constraint and click either the `first item` or `second item` dropdown you will see a tick next to this.

You need to untick this option and the 0 will then relate to the edge of the view rather than inset by 16 on the iPhone and 24 (I think) on the iPad.

Comment: Thx, thats what i didn't know